# How to hide the login / profile urls on top of comment box for a post

Tags: comments, urls, forms

See the image below, I need the urls to be hidden 
[image: comments form with url on top highlighted in RED]

Answer (score 1):

To hide with CSS, add this to your theme's style.css, or the Additional CSS section of the customizer.

```
.logged-in-as {
    display: none;
}
```

Or, to remove from the template completely, add this to your theme's, or preferably a child theme's, functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_logged_in', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a gem!!